# Is my interpretation of these correct?

Tags: grammar

Is my interpretation of these correct?

> I am not older than 6.
>   I am no older than 6.

(I am 6 and under)

> I am not much older than 6.

(I am older than 6, but not very different from being 6)

> I did nothing much more interesting than playing golf.

(What I did was more interesting than playing golf, but not by a huge extent.)

Answer (score 1):

> I am not older than 6. I am no older than 6. (I am 6 and under)

These sentences are strange because they imply that you don't know how old you are. If you know you're six years old, you would just say that. (An exception would be some sort of guessing game, for example, where you were trying to give hints.)

It would be more common referring to someone else: "He's no older than 40." (I would prefer this sentence to "He's not older than 40.") In this case, you're correct that I would be implying that he is either 40 or younger than 40. Probably younger, or else you'd use this construction:

> I am not much older than 6. (I am older than 6, but not very different from being 6)

Same comment applies in terms of making this statement in reference to yourself. If you said, "He's not much older than 40," I would interpret that statement to mean that he was no older than 43 or so. It would not be expressing with certainty, however, that the person was older than 40. If he turned out to be 38, then he's still "not much older than 40."

> I did nothing much more interesting than playing golf. (What I did was more interesting than playing golf, but not by a huge extent.)

Again, I would not say that what you did was definitely more interesting than playing golf. It may have been just as interesting, or even slightly less interesting. It just wasn't significantly more interesting. It's probably not significantly less interesting than playing golf either, or else you would have picked a different example.

Comment: I think a native speaker can talk about his or her own age, but usually not usually not *I am no older than 18.* It might be more like: *"I'm not eighteen! Does it matter?"* or something along that lone. I don't know if you will agree with me.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Very good point. If it's relevant whether you're older or younger than a certain age (e.g. the drinking age), you'd say, "I'm not 21" or "I'm not 21 yet", not "I'm no older than 21".

Comment: @DamkerngT. It's weird to say "I'm no older than 18" because (absent context to suggest otherwise) "no older than 18" appears to express an upper bound on an estimate, and as most people know their own age rather precisely, they have no reason to make this sort of estimate.